# Android contacts import

Tags: android

I am using an emulator API 8 and trying to import the contacts (more then 300 ones)
I can't get an instant messengers information after all. The contacts vcards are similar that one:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Lastname;Firstname
FN:Firstname Lastname
X-ANDROID-CUSTOM:vnd.android.cursor.item/nickname;Nickname;2;;;;;;;;;;;;;
TEL;HOME:000-000-000
TEL;WORK:000-00-00
EMAIL;HOME:test@testmailservertest.test
NOTE: notes
X-AIM:any messenger
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
```

I am using a system's "Contacts" application for import. Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: _trying to import the contacts_. How.? _I can't get an instant messengers information_. what have you tried to get it.? Please post the code where you are facing the problem to add more sense to your questions.

Comment: There is no code, I am using the system's tools. A "Contacts" application. But IMs information is not imported somehow.

Comment: So is your question this : you import a Contact(Vcard) but you are unable to locate your IM information once it is saved ? Right?

Comment: The IM information is in the vcard but it is not imported.  The rest of fields are imported well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a vCard parsing library like [ez-vcard](http://code.google.com/p/ez-vcard/):

```
String vcardStr = ...
VCard vcard = Ezvcard.parse(vcardStr).first();
List<RawType> aimProperties = vcard.getExtendedType("X-AIM");
String aim = aimProperties.get(0).getValue();
```